# How to write output from a for loop to a column in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Could someone explain how to write the output of a for loop to a column in the dataframe?

I have 3 sample tweets in a dataframe which contain unicode symbols. I would like to remove them using a for loop.

When I loop to print, I get what I want, but when I try to write the output to a column in the dataframe, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['content'] = row['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()
```

Comment: try `row['content']=
row['content'].apply(lambda x:x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())`

Comment: basically `apply()` method is also a loop under the hood...It is not working because youare not specifying the index try `row.loc[index,'content'] = row.loc[index,'content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()`

Comment: Thanks, it works! (After a little change from 'row' to 'df' of course). Could you please explain why my method won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using a wrong approach. Except in some very rare cases, you never want to loop over dataframe rows, mostly due to efficiency reasons.

Pandas has vectorized functions (such as 'apply') that do the job for you.

How `apply` works is by applying a function over each input of a specific dataframe / column.

So in your specific case, what you want to do is:

```py
df['new_content'] = df.content.apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()
```